# Core data/NSPersistentDocument marking file "clean" every time any field finishes editing

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I'm working with a document-based core-data OS X application. The problem I'm having is that whenever I edit any field on the document, after I press tab or click to something else (i.e. I finish editing/change focus), the document is marked as clean and undo is reset. When I try to save the file, however, the resulting document opens without the data I entered. What might be the problem, or, any pointers on where to look to fix this? Here's some stuff I know and things I've already tried:

I know it's not somehow saving because it never stops at the breakpoint in my overridden `writeSafelyToURL:(NSURL *)inAbsoluteURL ofType:(NSString *)inTypeName forSaveOperation:(NSSaveOperationType)inSaveOperation error:(NSError **)outError` and it also never sends an `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.

The documents are packaged in an `NSFileWrapper` directory with the core data store inside (and also some other files). I access the entities through an `NSObjectController` and a couple `NSArrayController`s. It happens with both core data properties and manually registered changes in the rest of the file wrapper.

Update: At the suggestion of Martin, I tried `NSUndoManager`'s notifications, and all I can seem to glean from it is that more than one undo manager is in play. If I add an observer for NSUndoManager, it won't post if I specify an object, and then if I don't, the notification object is not equal to `[self undoManager]`. I added `updateChangeCount` to my category on NSPersistentDocument, and it never gets called. `setDocumentEdited` basically confirmed that something about losing first responder is passing NO into that method. What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty silly considering how long this stumped me. I was working on some objects on load, and I accidentally set `[[self undoManager] disableUndoRegistration]` at both the points where I should disable and *enable*. It was a little more than that, though. A related element in Interface Builder needed to be checked `Prepares Content`. When I had done both those things, the problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

You could break on the method setDocumentEdited: of NSWindow to see which operation updates the change status.

In addition updateChangeCount: of NSDocument might be a place to take a look at.

NSUndoManager also posts several [Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000211-CJBGADBA) which can give additional hints what to look at.

Comment: I tried NSUndoManager, and all I can seem to glean from it is that more than one undo manager is in play. I added updateChangeCount to my category on NSPersistentDocument, and it never gets called. If I add an observer for NSUndoManager, it won't post if I specify an object, and then if I don't, the notification object is not equal to [self undoManager]. setDocumentEdited basically confirmed that something about losing first responder is passing NO into that method. I still feel like I'm at an impasse...